# CiviRules "Fatal Error" (4.6.22, WordPress)

Tags: error, civirules

We'd like to use and contribute to community development of CiviRules.

However, after install, we cannot get a simple test rule working. For example:

- Trigger: "When Contact of Any Type is Added"
- Action: "Add contact to group called [mailing list]"
- Delay: [none]

Is yielding no results.

**One thing we have noticed** is the following error message is delivered via CRON immediately after install of CiviRules and even before any rules are created:

---

**Fatal error**:  Can't use method return value in write context in **/..../org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php** on line **282**

---

Code at and near Line 282 mentions CRON although we did not make a CRON-triggered rule. Despite this, we're wondering if this error might explain why the simple rule did not work.

Can anyone point us to what this error may mean?

P.S. We can stop the error by disabling the scheduled jobs that are created on installation of CiviRules, but we're wondering if this error may be a hint as to why non-CRON triggers are not working.

Thanks.